# How do i execute a function when text changes in a cell? (google docs)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been lookin for a function to change the color of all cells in a row, when some text in a certain cell equals something. I found it here:

[Google Spreadsheet: Script to Change Row Color when a cell changes text;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703676/google-spreadsheet-script-to-change-row-color-when-a-cell-changes-text)

My question is, how can i execute this function, when the text changes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Search for the function onEdit.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_events

Answer (score 3):

Given *when some text in a certain cell equals something* Conditional Formatting may be much simpler. `onEdit` would be required if the change is from 'any value' to 'any other value' (so potentially from `y` to `x` as well from `x` to `y`) but CF can be triggered in cases such as:

"from `less than 100` to `100` (or to `100 or more than 100`), etc.",
"from `Pending` to `Complete` (or to any member of a list such as `Abandoned`, `Transferred`, `Rescheduled`, etc.)",
"from `more than a year left` to `less than a month` (or `a week`, or `4 days`, etc.)",
"from `any one of Red, Orange, Yellow` to `Green or Blue` (or `either Indigo or Violet`, etc.),
"from being a unique entry in a list to being a duplicate (ie without changing its own value becomes equal to any other entry)