# Google Sheets> I would like the cells in Column K to be deleted when one option is selected on column H

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like the cells in **Column K** to be deleted automatically when the option **"Approved"** has been selected in **column H.**

Column H has conditional format applied to it.

Sample>
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x_IqG3hyByuDfrPZzlgoTJ10jk_Cb-aekOKRrFJ9NGE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: see how to trigger the action with onEdit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391920  - you will also want to clear the cell (not delete it) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50166192

Answer (score 1):

Like Ricardo commented, you may want to set up an "onEdit" trigger for this if you want it to happen automatically. I also have this script set up so that it clears out the cell instead of deleting it; just as Ricardo suggested.

```
function DeleteColumnK() {
let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('YOUR_SHEET_ID').getSheetByName('Sheet1');
let sheetDB = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getMaxRows(),sheet.getMaxColumns()).getValues();
let columnH = sheetDB.map(function(r) {return r[7].toString();});
 
   for (i=0;i<sheet.getLastRow();i++) 
   {
    Logger.log(columnH[i])
    let rowNumber = (i+2);
    if (columnH[i] == "Approved")
      {
       sheet.getRange(rowNumber,11).setValue('');
      }
   }

}
```