# Row coloring in Google Apps Script onEdit and onOpen?

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, row, spreadsheet

I have create a Google form that submits data to a Google spreadsheet. I am trying to color code rows based on a value in a specific column - no problem. However, I am using the onEdit function and when a user submits the form, the rows do not change color. It is only when I edit the specific cell that the the row changes color, hence the onEdit function. Do, Google does not appear to see a form submission as an "edit" in the spreadsheet even though it is, technically, an edit. I have tried to copy and paste the function and rename it to onOpen, but that does not work either. What am I missing here? I have posted the code below and I really appreciate any help that you can afford. Also, I am a newb to scripting, so please be easy on me ;)

```
// Color code rows based on the status of the ticket
function onEdit(e) {
 if (e) { 
    var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    var r = e.source.getActiveRange(); 

    // If you want to be specific
    // do not work in first row
    // do not work in other sheets except "Sheet1"
    if (r.getRow() != 1 && ss.getName() == "Sheet1") {

        // E.g. status column is 6th (F)
        status = ss.getRange(r.getRow(), 6).getValue();

        // Specify the range with which You want to highlight
        // with some reading of API you can easily modify the range selection properties
        // (e.g. to automatically select all columns)
        rowRange = ss.getRange(r.getRow(),1,1,6);

        // This changes row color
        if (status == 'New') {
            rowRange.setBackgroundColor("#f26c4f");
        } else if (status == 'In Progress') {
            rowRange.setBackgroundColor("#fff568");
        } else if (status == 'Ordered') {
            rowRange.setBackgroundColor("#68baff");
        } else if (status == 'Completed') {
            rowRange.setBackgroundColor("#a2e7a5");  
        // DEFAULT
        } else if (status == '') { 
            rowRange.setBackgroundColor("#FFFFFF");
        }   
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: It's worthwhile mentioning that this code was taken from http://stackoverflow.com/a/13731812/1677912.

Comment: That is correct! Any idea how to make it do what I am asking?

Answer (score 0):

*"Google does not appear to see a form submission as an "edit" in the spreadsheet even though it is, technically, an edit"*

That's why there is an `On form submit` feature, see [documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers?hl=fr-FR#ActionTriggers), available from the script editor ressources > current script triggers
[image]

Comment: Hey Serge, Thank you for your quick response! I checked out the link you posted and I read it prior to posting my question, but it did not quite help with what I wanted to do. I also tried to rename the function and set multiple triggers for it, i.e. onOpen, onSubmit, onEdit, but it did not work. I want the rows to change color when a certain cell falls under a certain condition, no matter what the event. If the cell reads "New", it should be red, no matter if I change it or it was a form submission, which automatically marks it "New". How can I do this? Again, thank you for your help!!!

Comment: I can't get "On Form Submit" to work today. That's interesting - I use it frequently. I also notice that the "Legacy Forms" feature has disappeared. It's April 2 now, so it's not a joke. My guess is that since the new Forms don't actually "submit" to a spreadsheet, the trigger is broken.

Comment: So, you think this is on Google's side?