# Change cell color when edited, but only for a limited time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am very new to using Google App Script.

I am working on a Google Spreadsheet that will be edited by multiple users in our office. The spreadsheet is a schedule of order due dates. The information changes frequently (due dates are moved, new orders are added).

We would like to make it obvious when data has changed. I thought that changing the color of the cell would work as a good solution. However, I want the cell color to change back to white after some time as passed (a few hours, definitely no more than a day). I'm just looking for a temporary visual cue.

In a phrase: I want the background color of a cell to change each time the value of the cell is changed, but I want it to change back to white after a certain amount of time has passed.

Can this be done?

The closest solutions I found through searching is here:

[How to change a google spreadsheet row color, when a cell in the row is edited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171499/how-to-change-a-google-spreadsheet-row-color-when-a-cell-in-the-row-is-edited)

That appears to change the entire row's color when a cell is edited, but it does not change the color back later.

That question also references another that tries to accomplish something similar: [Google Spreadsheet: Script to Change Row Color when a cell changes text;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703676/google-spreadsheet-script-to-change-row-color-when-a-cell-changes-text)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its doable. Store your coloring actions somewhere like scriptDb. Install a  hourly trigger that reverts the old actions by querying for timestamp less than your limit (say new Date().getTime-1000*60*60*8 for older than 8 hours)