# How to stop a google app script from an infinite loop always executed when opening the Google Spreadsheet document?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I was trying to implement an improved solution of the google script suggested here: [Script to Change Row Color when a cell changes text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703676/google-spreadsheet-script-to-change-row-color-when-a-cell-changes-text).

However, after debugging my script, it occurred that **my document is not accessible anymore.** It seems that my script is erroneous and prevents my document from opening...  The consequence is that I cannot disable/edit/remove the associated google script and I am stuck!

Do you have a way to solve this blocking issue?

**UPDATE:** After further investigations, it seems that the reason of the problem is due to an infinite loop script called from the event trigger `onOpen()`. So my question can be reformulated to:

**How do you stop a Google Apps script that gets into an infinite loop?**

Can I use another script to kill the execution of this erroneous script ?

Answer (score 16):

This is an old post but just in case:

Go to your Google Apps Script project page, within the My Executions tab: https://script.google.com/home/executions.

Filter by status so you can find the running project. On the right you have the three dots menu where you can terminate the running project.

Comment: To anyone else reading this, this can stop problems from scripts stuck in a loop running in the background for whatever reason.  I may have inadvertently clicked "dismiss" on a script stuck in a loop rather than "Cancel", but I was able to stop the script from executing using the link above.

Answer (score 5):

Actually it is very simple. In your script loop, set a global var. Then when you want to stop it, wire up a script to set global var to false to a button image for example. Like this:

```
var RUNLOOP = true;

function YourLoop() {
  if (RUNLOOP) {
     // your code that does something every loop
  }
}

function stopLoop() {
  RUNLOOP = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a limit of about 6 minutes beyond which a script will stop executing. This is applicable to functions run on a trigger. But it is definitely worth waiting 6 minutes with your spreadsheet open.

Comment: But my spreadsheet does not open anymore. That is the problem ! Because the script is triggers by the onOpen() event

Comment: I created a similar spreadsheet with an infinite loop inside onOpen. I was able to access the spreadsheet despite the loop I didn't even have to wait the 6 minutes. The end of the loop was never reached but the spreadsheet was available for editing all the while. Did you use an installed trigger or simple trigger

Answer (score 0):

When you copy a spreadsheet, triggers created in the triggers menu are removed. Try making a copy of the offending spreadsheet and going from there.

If you have access to your browser history, use it to access just the code of your project.

Comment: If the function is onOpen, it is created by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the following address:

https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions

using the account on which the script is installed, find the script(using the name) and remove it so that it will no longer work--this action will remove all the permissions given to the script.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same question, and here is what I've been able to find:

The script will eventually [time out after 6 minutes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations).    At this time, **you can only manually stop an actively running Google Apps Script from within the Script Editor**, and even then, only if you kicked it off from within the Script Editor.

As a workaround, you can build in a "kill-switch" to your functions, but this might negatively impact performance and will require you to add logic to check the "kill switch" to every function you want to be able to stop.

Here is an example of such a "kill switch":
https://ctrlq.org/code/20112-suspend-google-script-execution