# How to stop execution of Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

Can I use something like **die()** *(in php)* at my Apps Script application?
I googled this question, the most acceptable solution is to throw new Error, but in this case I don't want to receive notification about script crash (as I not the only one who receives them).

I just want to terminate the script.

Comment: While this isn't quite a duplicate, any answer that answers this question for Javascript will typically answer it for GAS, as GAS primarily uses Javascript. A good place to start is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298839/is-it-possible-to-stop-javascript-execution, but if you just want the script to stop, you can also just 'return' nothing.

Comment: I believe the user was asking how to stop a Google Apps script once it has started running (for instance, if they accidentally kicked off a function that had an infinite loop), not how to make the function end when they were writing it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop a google app script from an infinite loop always executed when opening the Google Spreadsheet document?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892906/how-to-stop-a-google-app-script-from-an-infinite-loop-always-executed-when-openi)

Comment: @sandwich Thank you for correcting me.  My understanding of php is limited and I did not take the time to look up what `die()` actually does.  I have retracted my vote to close this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 11):

If you are in the code editor, and want to stop a script from running, you can click the "cancel" link in the toast display.

Or you can click "View" -> "Executions" from the code editor and then terminate the script.

You can also go directly to your executions at the link:

https://script.google.com/home/executions

[image: Terminate Execution]

Comment: What do you do when **terminate** is grayed out. Status is **paused**. I have alerts showing in my infinite loop. I am using the alerts because the logs in executions are taking hours to show up. I guess I just have to wait for it to time out but there should be some better way

Comment: It might be worth creating an issue on the Issue Tracker.  The link is: [https://issuetracker.google.com/](https://issuetracker.google.com/)  Or click the "Feedback" link in the bottom left of the Executions navigation bar.  Those are really the only two way to make Google aware of the problem.

Comment: Tried to but Create button stayed gray even though I included Component: Executions Termination option, Title : Executions Termination option should be available when script is paused and a description. ???

Comment: If you are trying to create a new issue on the Issue Tracker, make sure that you're logged into a Google account, and choose the category: `Public Trackers > Google Workspace Developers > Apps Script`

Comment: 173906140 terminate paused script

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help you create a new issue on the Issue Tracker.   I suggest that you join the Apps Script group at: [https://groups.google.com/g/google-apps-script-community](https://groups.google.com/g/google-apps-script-community) and explain your situation there.