# Terminate all running scripts in Google Dashboard

Tags: google-apps-script

I know how to terminate a running script, but how do you terminate all running scripts? Or is there a way to select some and terminate only those?

So far the only way is to click on each one, wait for the pop-up, confirm and just wait some more.

Answer (score 2):

https://script.google.com hasn't a way to terminate all the running scripts at once. By using this tool you have to terminate the running scripts one by one.

One alternative is to wait that the scripts finish or they exceed the maximum execution time limit:

- 6 minutes for consumer, G Suite free edition, Basic and Gov editions.
- 30 minutes for G Suite Business / Edu, Enterprise and Early Access

Related

- [How to stop execution of Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27601887/1595451)

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dashboard#terminating_executions
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quotas