# My Google Apps Script won't stop sending emails

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a script that executes when my Google Form is submitted. And I made a for loop that has no end, I didn't see the error until I've tried to test the script submitting one answer in my form. And this script send a e-mail to the e-mail that answered the form. Now I'm getting e-mails from this script without stop. And I have no idea how to stop this execution. In my executions of the project there is one execution that is with "unknown status", I believe this is the one inside the eternal loop and I can't end it.

What can I do?

Comment: Your `for` loop cannot work forever (thankfully). Either it ran out of resources or stopped after 6 minutes of execution ( or more, depending on your account tier ). If you send an email on each iteration of the loop, be prepared to receive *a lot* of the emails. Hopefully you will get around 100 (Gmail accounts are limited to 100 emails per day). That's why you test using dry runs :)

Answer (score 2):

To stop a script one option is to go to the script executions page, then for the execution that you want to stop, click on the corresponding three dots buttons and select Terminate.

[image]

[image]

Related

- [How to stop execution of Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27601887/1595451)