# If you are running a script in Google Apps Script and you have clicked Dismiss, the script continues to run. How do you stop this?

Tags: google-apps-script

[image]

By accident I clicked Dismiss and I had no idea on how to stop the script. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: In your situation, I thought that this thread might be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/q/27601887

Answer (score 0):

Open the script editor and hit the stop button at the top.

[image]

If you do not see this button, then the script is no longer running.

Answer (score 0):

You go to executions. Once you're there, hover on the function that is running. Click the 3 dots and terminate.

[image: Executions option in menu]