# How to change background color of row based on cell value? -Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to figure out how to do the following on Google Spreadsheets:
Put the letter 'x' in column A, row 2 (A column labeled "Status") and automatically change the background color of row 2 to RGB (244, 204, 204). I would want that for every row all the way down the spreadsheet.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Spreadsheet: Script to Change Row Color when a cell changes text;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703676/google-spreadsheet-script-to-change-row-color-when-a-cell-changes-text)

Answer (score 3):

Goto "Tools > Script Editor" and save and run the following code:

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rows = sheet.getRange('a1:z');
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var n = i+1;
    var bgColor = (values[i].indexOf('N/A') == -1) ? 'white' : 'red';
    sheet.getRange('a'+n+':z'+n).setBackgroundColor(bgColor);
  }
};
```

It basically changes the background color of a row cells from 'A' to 'Z' when any of the cell contains the value 'N/A'.

Comment: that only changes the background color of the individual cell rather than the whole row.

Comment: Updated my answer to highlight the entire row

Answer (score 0):

using onEdit() trigger you can use this code

```
function onEdit(e) {
    if (e.range.getColumn() ==1){
      e.range.setBackgroundRGB(244, 204, 204);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

@Dan Sudhakar's response works for the whole row as long as you adjust **sheet.getRange('a'+n+':z'+n)** where the **:z** to the last column in your sheet. I do need additional help on this however. How do I setup multiple ranges? I changed what would make sense to me but it works only for adjustments made to column C now and ignores A.

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rows = sheet.getRange('a1:a');
  var rows = sheet.getRange('c1:c'); // ADDED THIS //
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var n = i+1;
    var bgColor = (values[i].indexOf('N/A') == -1) ? 'white' : 'red';
    sheet.getRange('a'+n+':b'+n).setBackgroundColor(bgColor);
   sheet.getRange('c'+n+':d'+n).setBackgroundColor(bgColor);  // ADDED THIS //
  }
};
```