# setBackground() or setFontColor not working in GAS

Tags: google-apps-script

I was having trouble getting my script to highlight a range and after debugging for a bit, realized that there seems to be something wrong with the call of type

```
range.setBackground("name of color");
```

So, I went to GAS reference website and used the example from their page: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setFontColor(String)

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var cell = sheet.getRange("B2");
cell.setFontColor("red");
```

This code results in !ERROR.
If I force a return before setFontColor() call, all is fine. (and by fine I mean it returns from the function without an error, but of course, without having set the color).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You havent put enough info, but i assume you are calling your function from a cell formula as a custom function. See the docs, used like that you cant change a cell other than the current cell.

Comment: You are right, I forgot to mention that I am trying to create a custom function, which I thought I could call from a cell formula as a custom function and it would change the color of a specified range. so, I want a row to change color based on the value of a specific cell. I guess I have to figure out how to have some kind of "self-refreshing" script run on top of my doc which would check cell contents every once in a while.

Comment: Exactly. Use a time trigger to refresh every minute, plus i suggest you add a menu to 'format now'. Make sure to check spreadsheets native custom formatting. Its much better in the new sheets and can reference ranges

Comment: see here regading sheet's native custom formatting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545961/google-spreadsheet-conditional-formatting-based-on-another-cell-value

Comment: Ok, got it now. Used this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703676/google-spreadsheet-script-to-change-row-color-when-a-cell-changes-text Then learned about onEdit(e)

Comment: Yes, onEdit can do it too, and more generally onChange. There are a few issues to deal with, make sure to test it on users that are not the spreasheet owner. Also, some actions dont trigger onChange, for example "undo", so have a time trigger too to deal with those.

Comment: onChange has the advantage of catching more events (onEdit wont catch deleted rows for example), and it has FULL oauth mode (see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events)

Answer (score 3):

I can't reproduce the error. The following code work as expected:

```js
/* CODE FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES */
function setFontAndBackgroundColorCell() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var cell = sheet.getRange('B2');
  cell.setFontColor('yellow');
  cell.setBackground('red');
  cell.setValue('TEST');
}
/* CODE FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES */
```

[image]