# How to set background color in a row, when a cell has data over a specific value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to make a Google Spreadsheet script that changes rows' background color whenever a specific cell in every row of a single column has a value over of 100%. After searching and trying to configure so many scripts for my needs, I am not in the best situation to say that I made it.

What I am trying to do:

- Here is the [link to my Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rSlk7UQBEo2cJqFfOxI_RtPsNCzLDm-IJRUvOZ_Jm8g/edit?usp=sharing).
- As you can see, this is a sheet with students' names and their degrees. This sheet has 5 columns and 500 rows.
- I want to set a background color (for instance: *#2fb726*) in every row in which a student has a degree over or equal to 100.
- Here is what I am thinking...

  ```
  Dim green = #2fb726
  Dim white = #ffffff

  For E_rows = 2 to 500 
    If E(E_rows) >=100 Then
      A(E_rows).backgroundcolor = green
      B(E_rows).backgroundcolor = green
      C(E_rows).backgroundcolor = green
      D(E_rows).backgroundcolor = green
      E(E_rows).backgroundcolor = green
    Else
      A(E_rows).backgroundcolor = white
      B(E_rows).backgroundcolor = white
      C(E_rows).backgroundcolor = white
      D(E_rows).backgroundcolor = white
      E(E_rows).backgroundcolor = white
    End If
  Next E_rows
  ```

How could this be in Google Spreadsheet script?

Comment: Thank you @tim for your help in tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can actually do this with conditional formatting:

for apply to range: enter A2:E500

and then for "format cells if... " choose custom formula and enter:

```
=$E$2:$E>=100
```

and choose whatever color you want... here is an example screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No expert but maybe something like this:

```
  var green = "#2fb726"
  var white = "#ffffff"

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  for (var i=2; i<500; i++) {
    var range = sheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, 5);
    var color;
    if (sheet.getRange(i, 5).getValue() >= 100) {
      color = green;
    } else {
      color = white;
    }

    range.setBackground(color);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Gonna go on ahead what I found while digging around the community.
I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3860310/6124253) where it shows you how to change the background color (cell color) of the row based on the value of a specific cell.

And since you mentioned you want this to run via the script, I presumed that you are hoping for this to run automatically? So looked around and found this page on [creating custom menus](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus?csw=1#custom_menus_in_google_docs_sheets_or_forms), where in the example, it calls the `onOpen()` function.

So I modified the code from the answer on the similar post, called it inside the `onOpen` function, saved the script, refreshed the doc, and managed to get a result like this:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you use Conditional Formatting. In cell A2 set Conditional Formatting:

Range A2:E50

Custom formula is:

=$E$2:$E$50>=100

Select your color

Adjust the range as needed.