# Google Sheet accept colour from neighbour cell

Tags: colors, google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I wanted to know if I can solve this little problem in Google spreadsheets with conditional formatting but without a script.

Question 1: a blank Cell A1 has a red background colour and I change it to green manually. How can I get cell B1 to change from red to green too without touching it?

Comment: Welcome. This site has use guidelines that are different from other similar sites. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask] to learn the basics about asking questions here.

Answer (score 0):

Google Sheets doesn't have a built-in feature that detects cell background changes. The alternative is to use a script, like the one on  [Google Spreadsheet: Script to Change Row Color when a cell changes text;](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3703676/1595451)

Comment: Thank you Rubén. Can somebody help me with this script?

Comment: It's worth to note that your question said "without a script". I added a link to a question that could help you.