# Format cell color based on the cell text content

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I want to accomplish something like this:

I have a sort of "Relational" Spreadsheet, and I want rows to be colored according.

[image]

I manually choosing a unique color for each Category on the "Categories" Sheet or generating a unique color based on the string content, either would work for my use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best solution but it works
[image]

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e){
    var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    var range = e.source.getActiveRange();

    var r1 = range.getRow();
    var c1 = range.getColumn();
    var rowsCount = range.getNumRows();

    for(var i=0; i<rowsCount; i++){

      var row = ss.getRange(r1+i,1,1,ss.getMaxColumns());
      updateRow(row, ss);
    }
  }
}

function updateRow(row, ss){
  if (ss.getName() == "Entries") { // This is the sheet name

    var cell = row.getCell(1,1);
    var firstCellValue = cell.getValue();

    if(firstCellValue){
      cell.setBackgroundColor(stringToColor(firstCellValue));
    }
    else{
      cell.setBackgroundColor(null);
    }
  }
}


function stringToColor(str) {
  var hash = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    hash = str.charCodeAt(i) + ((hash << 5) - hash);
  }
  var colour = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var value = (hash >> (i * 8)) & 0xFF;
    colour += ('00' + value.toString(16)).substr(-2);
  }
  return colour;
}
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13731773/938822) answer

Answer (score 0):

in conditional formatting select the range you want to apply colors, select color, 
choose **`Text is exactly`** and set value:

[image]

Comment: I didn't want to create a rule for each category